# Runtime Error : Reference binding to null pointer ot type 'int' (Leetcode Problem)

Tags: c++, vector, runtime-error

Trying to solve [Leetcode problem #448: Find All Numbers Disappeared in an Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-all-numbers-disappeared-in-an-array/). The Variable `nums` represents a vector containing a list of numbers (including the disappeared ones).

```
   vector <int> temp,result;
    int max = *max_element(nums.begin(),nums.end());
    for(int i=1;i<=max;i++)
        temp.push_back(i);
        
    for(int i=0;i<int(temp.size());i++)
    {
        if(count(nums.begin(),nums.end(),temp[i])==0)
        {
            result.push_back(temp[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
```

There seems to be no compile time error. But Runtime throws an error saying:

```
Line 811: Char 16: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_iterator.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:820:16
```

Comment: Are you sure `nums` has data in it?  If not, then `*max_element(nums.begin(),nums.end())` would certainly be a likely candidate for the error as you would be dereferencing a "null iterator".

Comment: *There seems to be no compile time error* -- All this means is that there are no syntax error.  It has no bearing on whether the program is logically correct.  If all that was required is to have programs compile with no errors, then there would be no bugs in C++ programs.

Answer (score 2):

The input vector `nums` could be empty. The problem raises while calling `max_element` function with an empty vector. You can simple test the code by passing an empty vector (e.g., `[]`) to the function.

The easiest solution is to check whether the input vector `nums` is empty in the beginning of the function. Like this:

```
    vector <int> temp, result;
    if(nums.size() == 0) return result;
        
    int max = *max_element(nums.begin(),nums.end());
    ...
    ...
```

This will solve the runtime error you are facing here.